# Temporarily simulate being offline programmatically

Tags: web-access, internet

Today I am running Mathematica from a computer that is permanently connected to our university network. Because of a number of reasons, I am not allowed to disconnect my computer from our network.

My conflict is that I have some code I wish to test that depends on whether the computer is connected to the Internet or otherwise. **How can I pretend my computer is not connected to the Internet for testing?**

I know about `$NetworkConnected` to check if the computer is connected, but temporarily setting it to `False` with `Block` does not seem to work.

As a simple example of code that needs an Internet connection for testing purposes, you can use `CurrencyConvert`.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can set `$AllowInternet` to `False` (or just turn off your WiFi or unplug the cable).

Comment: `$AllowInternet` looks like it does what I need, but I did not find this in documentation.

Comment: @宮元亜衣 You can turn off accessing the internet using the GUI in the preferences. I believe `$AllowInternet` does exactly the same (and toggling the GUI toggles this variable too). I don't know where it's documented. It's probably undocumented (but widely known).

Comment: For limited documentation use `Names["*Internet*"]` followed by `??$AllowInternet`

Answer (score 8):

A general solution for Windows is to run an application (such as *Mathematica*) inside a [Sandboxie](https://www.sandboxie.com) sandbox, for which **Sandbox Settings** > **Restrictions** > **Internet Access** has been set to "No program can access the Internet."